# Finding surface area of revolution

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, rotations, area

Can anyone help me with finding the surface area of a solid of revolution of f(x) about the x axis for the interval [1,6].  It's supposed to be able to be done without needing calculus but I am having trouble figuring it out.

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  &  1 \leq x< 2\\ 
1/2 &  2 \leq x< 3\\ 
. &          .\\ 
. &          .\\
1/n &  n\leq x< n+1\\ 
\end{cases}$

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solid consists of cylinders, where the radius of a particular cylinder is the value of $f$ at that part. The wanted surface area is the "outer parts" of the cylinders. Does this help?

Comment: so can I just use the formula for surface area and use this:  $\sum_{1}^{6}$(2$\pi$(n)+2$\pi$(n)$^2$)?